# How to edit LiveData<PageList> before setting to adapter

Tags: android, android-room, pagedlist

I use this
[link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.html)
 to make a pagedList from Room. But i must fetch other data from another remote before set adapter
How can i edit LiveData> results before set data?